# Navigate from datagrid to dataform in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my Silverlight-3 application.
When I select a row in the datagrid, I need to able to go to a new page which contains a dataform having a detailed view of that particular row. 
I dont want to use "RowDetailsTemplate" property in datagrid.
I want to navigate to a new page which contains my dataform.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are MANY ways to achieve what you want to do.

If you are looking for a deep-linking approach, you can look into the [Silverlight Navigation Framework](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx) which is shipped with Silverlight 3.

You might also look into using a [ChildWindow](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/29/silverlight-3-s-new-child-windows.aspx) as a modal dialog to display the page.

For displaying the data item, you might consider using the [DataForm](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/dataform-control/) control.